# Both buttons are checked in MaterialToggleButton Android while only one should

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-togglebutton

I have a `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` like this

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:singleSelection="true">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/bYes"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="YES" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/bNo"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NO" />
        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

I am listening to the changes happening on this ToggleGroup like this

```
toggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
//            println("checkedId ${checkedId} $isChecked")
            if (checkedId == R.id.bYes){
                println("yes is checked "+1)
            }else{
                println("no is checked "+0)
            }
        }
```

But what's happening is, both buttons are checked when I am just switching from YES to NO. I am getting the logs like this

```
I/System.out: yes is checked 1
I/System.out: no is checked 0
```

whenever I switch from YES to NO. Shouldn't this only give me the button that is checked not the button that is unchecked?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `setSingleSelection(true)`? it allows you ony one button to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter the checked button with the `isChecked` flag:

```
toggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
    if(isChecked) {
        when(checkedId) {
            R.id.bYes -> println("YES is checked")
            R.id.bNo -> println("NO is checked")
        }
    } else {
        when(checkedId) {
            R.id.bYes -> println("YES is not checked")
            R.id.bNo -> println("NO is not checked")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add `setSingleSelection(true)` and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the button programmatically.
**MaterialButtonToggleGroup** provides the other way to check, uncheck and clear the checked buttons states.

```
toggleGroup.check(R.id.bYes) // Checks a specific button
toggleGroup.uncheck(R.id. bYes) // Unchecks a specific button
toggleGroup.clearChecked()
```

Comment: You would still need a check change listener to get which button is checked